# USB wifi adapter keeps dropping connection (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: wireless, usb

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my desktop machine. I connect to the internet through an **EDIMAX EW-7612UAn V2** USB wifi adapter. The problem is that the connection keeps dropping randomly, but the network manager at the top right keeps showing connected status.

I also have Windows 10 installed in the machine, and I face no such issues when I boot into windows.

There are several threads in ubuntuforums in which this problem is reported for laptops, but none provide the solution for a USB wifi adapter. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to take a look at my question about this. It was mostly solved for me. [Wifi Unstable with Edimax EW-7811Un](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896212/wifi-unstable-with-edimax-ew-7811un)

Comment: I blacklisted the rtl8192cu module same as you and disabled the power saving in network manager, and so far it seems to have worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for you too!